# why is it I got undefined variable even though it is clearly defined in my code?

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on a project using symfony2.I have a function that can find missing data, with pagination and so with search. My problem now is that I got an error stating:

> Notice: Undefined variable: data in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Supplier\src\Supplier\SupplierBundle\Controller\SupplierController.php
>   line 375

Here is my controller code:

```
public function missingDataAction(Request $request,$page){
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $refNumber = $request->query->get('poNumber');
        $invNumber = $request->query->get('invNumber');

        $max_records = 15 ;
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $asns =  $em->getRepository('SupplierBundle:SupplierTransactionDetail')->findDocs($invNumber,$refNumber,'856');

        foreach ($asns as $asn){
            $ref_number [] = $asn->getRefNumber(); 
            $data = $em->getRepository('SupplierBundle:SupplierTransaction')->findMissingData($refNumber, $page, 15);

            $count = $data->count();
            $pagination = array(
                'page' => $page,
                'route' => 'supplier_missingData',
                'route_params' => array()
            );

            if ($max_records > 0 ) {
                $pagination['pages_count'] = max(ceil($count / $max_records), 1 );
            }
        }
        return $this->render('SupplierBundle:Supplier:missingData.html.twig', array('result' => $data, 'pagination' => $pagination ));

    }
```

I don't know what's wrong. It was clearly defined the data, but still it gives me an error. I don't know what to do.Hope someone can I see what I can't see.Can somebody help me?

Comment: the last part: the return statement

Comment: Try doing `var_dump($asns);` and I'm pretty sure the answer will be obvious.

Comment: Josh's answer is correct.

Comment: when I tried putting my return statement inside the loop it gives me another error : "The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?"

Comment: Any time you have a return statement inside a loop you have likely done something wrong.

Comment: so what to do , because if the search result is null it must return something like "no result found"

Comment: Your whole loop is pointless. It serves absolutely no purpose. You only use `$asn` once to set the variable `$ref_number` and then you never use `$ref_number`

Comment: can you give an example   of what you mean?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261541/notify-new-users-when-their-comment-will-not-ping-anyone

Comment: how is it related to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario where you never enter the loop, you return using the data variable, but it has not yet been defined

Just move your data variable definition (the line below) ... to above your for loop

```
$data = $em->getRepository('SupplierBundle:SupplierTransaction')->findMissingData($refNumber, $page, 15);

$pagination = array(
            'page' => $page,
            'route' => 'supplier_missingData',
            'route_params' => array()
        );

foreach ($asns as $asn){
    $ref_number [] = $asn->getRefNumber();
    ...
```

Comment: so what should I do? put it inside the loop?

Comment: Looks to me like you can just move that line to before the loop.

Comment: I would not do that, because otherwise your loop will exit after the first iteration. I would just move that line above the loop

Comment: I tried that ,,and it gives me another error : it is pagination again that is undefined

Comment: oops... sorry i missed that one, move that variable above the loop too, as it also is in your return statement. i have changed my answer above to show the fix

Comment: can I ask another question? how can I put something like no result found in there?

Comment: because once it doesn't found what the user search it will just display the table blank.

Answer (score 0):

There's two things that I can think of.

One, the function `$em->getRepository('SupplierBundle:SupplierTransaction')->findMissingData($refNumber, $page, 15)` is not returning a value, and so making $data undefined.

The other thing I can think of is that $asns is an empty array, and so the foreach loop never runs. And so when you use $data in your return statement, it hasn't been defined because the code in the foreach loop that defines it was never run.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to answer the question in the comments `to put a no result message`  I'll  give you the short answer, if you need one more in depth might be better to post it as a separate question

```
 if( count( $asns ) ){
   foreach( $asns as   $asn ){
 .....
     }
}else{ 
     //add no search message to result array here
 }
```

Comment: thanks , but how can I do it because when I display my search results it is just the same page as my display for all transaction and everything is displayed in a table. because when i search I just redirect it on the same page as for all transaction, and what i want for the "no result found" is also to redirect it on the same page but just colspan the whole table? how can I do it? futher help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As I said you might want to post that as a separate question, that depends more on the format of your page.  It's Twig templates right?

Comment: yes , so you mean you I must put it in my twig file?

Comment: in my twig file, I just put it in a table and put some loop,, that's all. what and where can I insert it so it will give me my desire output?

Comment: No I mean I don't use Twig, but I assume if it is to be displayed it has something to do with how you output stuff to the screen.  It's probably to broad to be asked inside another question.